# Vue selected prop not working with v-model

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

The `:selected` prop is not selecting the target `option` in Vue2 when i use `v-model` for `select` :

**Template**

```
...
<select v-model="form.item">
    <option :value="item.id" v-for="(item, index) in items" :selected="item.status == 2">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
...
```

**Script**

```
data: function () {
    return {
        items: [{id:1, name: "foo", status: 1},{id: 3, name: "bar", status: 2}],
        form: {item: null}
    }
}
```

In this case , after mounted there is no selected option.

How can i fix this?

**Note**

When i remove `v-model` it works fine (target `option` is selected by default) but i don't have the value of the selected `option` in `form.item`

Comment: v-model and :selected don't work together. It is explained in the official doc. You can only use one of both.

Comment: @hannesneukermans do you know any good solution for this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**v-model will ignore** the initial value, checked or **selected** attributes.
found on any form elements

The solution is to remove :selected binding. and use data props to bind to v-model

```
<select v-model="form.selectedItem">
   <option :value="item.id" v-for="(item, index) in items">{{ item.name }}
   </option>
</select>
```

declare vue instance as

```
data() {
 return {
  selectedItem: 2
 }
}
```

[link to official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage)

Comment: for some reason when this is set as a string or null the v-model wasn't working for me... changing the declaration to 0 fixed this. I'm not sure why though

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is by using `$refs` instead of v-model.

```
<select ref="selectedItem">
   <option v-for="(item, index) in items" :value="item.id" :selected="item.status == 2">
      {{ item.name }}
   </option>
</select>
```

Then to get the value of the selected item, call...

```
this.$refs.selectedItem.value
```

Comment: Why do you need the index in the iterations?

Comment: @GaryVaughan In this particular example it is redundant as it is not used anywhere. I just copied and updated the code from the question. However Vuejs documentation recommends using index (or unique record id) in v-for iterations to define unique :key - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: OIC.  Thanks for clearing that up!  That is actually how I did my options:

<option v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :value="item.id">

Your answer regarding "this.$refs.selectedItem.value is what did the trick for me to get my disabled option(0) as the selected item in the dropdown.  Otherwise it was just a blank select with the option hidden until click.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select v-model="selectedGroup">
    <option :value="false" :selected="selectedGroup == false">All</option>
    <option v-if="organization.groups" v-for="group in organization.groups" :value="group">{{ group }}</option>
</select>
```